# How can I create an extended calendar in AutoSys that always runs annually on Nov 1st, regardless of whether or not it is a holiday or weekend?

Tags: calendar, autosys

I need to create an extended calendar in AutoSys so that the schedule always runs annually on Nov 1st, regardless of what day of week it is or whether or not it is a holiday. I'm unclear on what condition information I can utilize to establish this criteria.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the "generate preview" option in AutoSys only shows the calendar schedule for the current year, despite the fact that it allows the user to select future years in the preview. I believe this is the correct way to accomplish this:

condition: nov#1